# Error: android.widget.CompoundButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
public class PassActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paris_foot);

        card_resultat_double_chance_x2_4plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_x2_4plus);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_4plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_12_4plus);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_4plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_1x_4plus);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x2_4moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_x2_4moin);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_4moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_12_4moin);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x2_3moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_x2_3moin);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_3moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_12_3moin);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_3moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_1x_3moin);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x_2plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_x_2plus);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_2plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_12_2plus);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_2plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_1x_2plus);
        card_equipe1_but_non =findViewById(R.id.card_equipe1_but_non);
        card_equipe2_but_oui =findViewById(R.id.card_equipe2_but_oui);
        card_equipe2_but_non =findViewById(R.id.card_equipe2_but_non);
        card_double_chance_1xnon =findViewById(R.id.card_double_chance_1xnon);
        card_double_chance_12oui =findViewById(R.id.card_double_chance_12oui);
        card_double_chance_x2non =findViewById(R.id.card_double_chance_x2non);
        card_double_chance_x2oui =findViewById(R.id.card_double_chance_x2oui);
        card_resultat_2equip_1oui =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_2equip_1oui);
        card_resultat_2equip_1non =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_2equip_1non);
        card_resultat_2equip_xoui =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_2equip_xoui);
        card_resultat_2equip_xnon =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_2equip_xnon);
        card_resultat_2equip_2oui =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_2equip_2oui);
        card_resultat_2equip_2non =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_2equip_2non);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_2moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_1_2moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_2moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_x_2moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_2moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_2_2moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_2plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_1_2plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_2plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_x_2plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_2plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_2_2plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_3moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_1_3moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_3moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_x_3moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_3moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_2_3moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_3plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_1_3plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_3plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_x_3plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_3plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_2_3plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_4moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_1_4moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_4moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_x_4moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_4moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_2_4moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_4plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_1_4plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_4plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_x_4plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_4plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_2_4plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_5moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_1_5moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_5moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_x_5moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_5moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_2_5moin);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_5plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_1_5plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_5plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_x_5plus);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_5plus =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_nbre2but_2_5plus);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_2moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_1x_2moin);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_2moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_12_2moin);
        card_resultat_double_chance_2x_2moin =findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_double_chance_2x_2moin);
        card_butteur_name =findViewById(R.id.card_butteur_name);

        card_resultat_fin_1barx4moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbar14plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbarx3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar14moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar24plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbar13moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1barx3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar13moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar23plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2barx3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar13plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbar23plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbarx3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbar13plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar23plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1barx3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar13plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar22moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbar11.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1bar11.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbarx0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar25moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2barx5moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar15moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbar25moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbarx5moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbar15moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar25moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1barx5moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar15moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar25plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2barx5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar15plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbar25plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbarx5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_xbar15plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar25plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1barx5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_1bar15plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar24moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2barx4moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_2bar14moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_but_exact_6plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_but_exact_5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_but_exact_4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_but_exact_3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_but_exact_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_but_exact_0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_but_exact_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2equip_but_non3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2equip_but_non3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2equip_but_oui3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2equip_but_oui3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x2_5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_5moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_5moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_resultat_but_x_2moin_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_resultat_but_1_2moin_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_double_x2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_double_12.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_double_1x.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_2bar2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_xbar2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_1bar2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_2barx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_xbarx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_1barx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_2bar1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_xbar1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_fin_mitemps_1bar1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_2bar24.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_2barx4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_2bar14.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbar24.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbarx4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbar14.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1bar24.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1bar24.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1barx4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1bar14.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_2bar23.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_2bar13.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbar23.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbar13.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1bar23.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1bar13.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_2bar22.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_2barx2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbar22.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_1bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_xbar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_2bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_double_chance_12non.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_but_1Moin_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_but_1Plus_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2Ekip_but_non_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2Ekip_but_oui_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbar21.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_2bar21.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1bar12.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_1barx2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbar12.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_fin_but_xbarx2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_2_2_0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_x_2_0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_1_2_0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_2_1_0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_x_1_0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_1_1_0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_2_0_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_x_0_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_1_0_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_2_0_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_x_0_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_handicap_1_0_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_6M.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_6P.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_double_chance_1xoui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_5M.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_5P.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_4M.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_4P.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_3M.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_3P.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_2P.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_1M.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_1P.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_nbre_2M.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_equipe_non.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_equipe_oui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_double_chance_x2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_x.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_double_chance_1x.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_4moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x2_3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_equipe1_but_oui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_pair_but.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_impair_but.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2temps_Bar_3Moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2temps_Bar_3Plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2temps_Bar_2Moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2temps_Bar_2Plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2temps_Bar_1Moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_2temps_Bar_1Plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_bar_non.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_bar_oui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_temps_egalite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_temps_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_temps_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_2but_pLus_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_1but_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_0but_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_but_3Moin_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_but_3Plus_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_but_2Moin_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_1temps_but_2Plus_bar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x2_4plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_4plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_4plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x2_4moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_4moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x2_3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_x_2plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_2plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_2plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_equipe1_but_non.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_equipe2_but_oui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_equipe2_but_non.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_double_chance_1xnon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_double_chance_12oui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_double_chance_x2non.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_double_chance_x2oui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_2equip_1oui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_2equip_1non.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_2equip_xoui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_2equip_xnon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_2equip_2oui.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_2equip_2non.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_2moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_2moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_2moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_2plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_2plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_2plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_3moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_3plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_4moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_4moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_4moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_4plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_4plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_4plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_5moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_5moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_5moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_1_5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_x_5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_nbre2but_2_5plus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_1x_2moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_12_2moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
        card_resultat_double_chance_2x_2moin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onRadioButtonCheckedListener);
    }


    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onRadioButtonCheckedListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked) return;
            if (previousCheckedCompoundButton != null) {
                previousCheckedCompoundButton.setChecked(false);
                previousCheckedCompoundButton = buttonView;
            } else {
                previousCheckedCompoundButton = buttonView;
            }

            int selectedRadioBtnId = buttonView.getId();
            if (selectedRadioBtnId != -1) {
                previousCheckedCompoundButton = findViewById(selectedRadioBtnId);

            }
        }
    };

}
```

```
Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CompoundButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CompoundButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at cg.ocsnetwork.parissms.foot.ParisFootActivity.onCreate(ParisFootActivity.java:479)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a LOT of widgets in that view and it is really hard to debug it. I would recommend you to use either [viewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or [dataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) to avoid nullpointer exceptions and for the code to be more maintainable and readable.

Having said that, you are probably adding that listener to one (or more) of those widgets who might not be present or well defined in your layout. Try setting breakpoints in each one of the assignations and debug it to see in which one it breaks so you can fix that (or those) widget in specific.